# Shortcut for adding an equation in powerpoint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, equation-editor

I mean to add an equation in Powerpoint via keyboard shortcut.
Both

1. Within an existing text box, and
2. In a new text box.

I have a laptop with no numeric keypad and Latin American keyboard. E.g., characters ***+***, ******* (as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) and ***~*** (as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) are all 3 in the same key.

When entering text in an existing text box, typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> creates math environment, covering item 1 above.

I found no shortcut for item 2 directly.
As an alternative, looking to achieving this with 2 steps (1. Create text box, 2. Same as above), I found no shortcut for creating a text box, so this does not work either.

Is there a shortcut that I could use?

I mean to avoid the Enigma-type sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Alt+N+E+I works for me in Powerpoint (Equation editor or LaTeX mode).

Alt+= does work in Word but not always in Powerpoint. Perhaps depends on the keyboard you have (e.g., non-U.S.?).